# How can I fix a GameObject along one axis only when it is part of another object in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

Hello I have an Object player and inside player, I have an object Boundary which is supposed to follow the player as he moves up or down only? (As the player moves right or left I don't want the boundary object to move. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want it to move? then why attach it to the player object?

Comment: I want it to follow the player only vertically. but not horizontally

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do, if you want to get the best possible assistance. Pictures would help. Your current description is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a child object?
If not;
Create another object.
Get a transform reference to it.
Update its transform each frame like so;

```
object.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, object.position.y);
```